# Join 2 datasets from 2 cubes into one chart on SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, mdx, olap, reportbuilder3.0

I would like to ask, I have 2 datasets from 2 cubes, very similar data (only measure is the different), and i would like to combine both data into 1 chart..
Here is the data from the dataset:
[image: First Dataset]

[image]

Is there any way to combine those data into 1 chart with 2 series?

This is my goal : 
[image]

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: is it SQL Server 2012 version? You may take a look at Lookup/LookupSet functions.

Comment: yes SQL Server 2012 version.. i already try lookup but how if it was multiple lookup / nested lookup? because i didnt have 1 unique id/fields to lookup, i have to lookup at 4 fields to find the matched one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for this problem.. So ive tried the lookup function but it only look for one field, and i have to lookup at multi fields.. so i join them in one field like

```
=Sum(LookUp(Fields!xxx.Value+"-"+Fields!yyy.Value,Fields!2xxx.Value+"-"2yyy.Value,Fields!LookFor.Value,"Dataset2"))
```

Thanks :)